# SAS university edition error : ERROR: Physical file does not exist, /opt/sasinside/SASConfig/Lev1/SASApp/C:\Learning\mydata.txt

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS i just wrote download my first program in sas but getting the following error :

> ERROR: Physical file does not exist,
>   /opt/sasinside/SASConfig/Lev1/SASApp/C:\Learning\mydata.txt.

below is my code :

```
data demographic;
infile "C:\Learning\mydata.txt";
input Gender $ Age Height Weight;
run;

title "Gender Frequencies";
proc freq data=demographic;
tables Gender;
run;

title "Summary Statistics";
proc means data=demographic;
var Age Height Weight;
run;
```

Comment: Follow the installation instructions for setting up shared folders.  http://support.sas.com/kb/53/333.html

Comment: You need to place your file in the Shared Folder and then access it using the path /folders/myfolders/your file name.

Answer (score 2):

For the SAS university edition virtual application  , it thinks you are on a unix machine .
-> create 'myfolders' as per the install document.
-> got to Server files and folders . under your folder there will be a ser folder .. something like 'sasuser.v94'
-> right click on 'sasuser.v94' and select upload files .
-> upload all the files , and you will see the files under the user folder.

you can useinfile stement like this in your code
 => infile "/folders/myfolders/sasuser.v94/mydata.txt";

Comment: Although you can use the SASUSER folder I wouldn't recommend it. Adding files to myfolders is enough. A user can also use their OS and move the files into the shared folder, no need to upload anything. And the VM is UNIX.